# DirectorySearcher object data retrieving not working on Azure hosted application

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, directorysearcher

This code used to work for me in order to retrieve the AD information of a user when passing ID by parameter.

```
    public UsersDTO GetUserFromActiveDirectoryByID(string userID)
    {
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();            
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(name=" + userID + "))";
        SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
        SearchResult userProperty = results[0];    
        UsersDTO user = new UsersDTO();
        if (userProperty.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
        {                
            user.fullName = userProperty.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();                
            user.email = userProperty.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();             
        }
        return user;
    }
```

It worked while the application service was hosted in another server, but now that it has been migrated to Azure, the FindAll command (also FindOne was tested) returns "There was an error retrieving the  data.","Status":400,"Detail":"Access is denied."

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the `SearchRoot` of your `DirectorySearcher`. [The documentation for `SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot#remarks) says:

> If SearchRoot is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), the search root is set to the root of the domain that your server is currently using.

If the other server was joined to the domain that you are trying to search, then that's why it was working. But that is no longer true when you're on Azure.

So you need to specify the `SearchRoot` to point it at your domain:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com");
```

This may also introduce issue of whether you can actually access your domain controllers from Azure. You may need to open firewall rules to allow it, depending on how your environment is setup.

Comment: I tried this with the LDAP from the domain of the required AP and now the error is different: "There was an error retrieving the  data.","Status":400,"Detail":"The server is not operational."

Comment: @LaureanoBonilla That sounds like a network issue. Make sure your domain is accessible from Azure.